# invalid date error in the date command linux

Tags: linux, shell, date

In the script I am using the command

```
CURRENT_DATE_tmp=`date -d $CURRENT_DATE +%Y%m%d`.
```

It gives error `` date: invalid date `+%Y%m%d' ``
what may be the reason. I know that the variable CURRENT_DATE have value in it.

Comment: Can you demonstrate to us the error when the variable has a value? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

`date -d $CURRENT_DATE` will print the date corresponding to the `$CURRENT_DATE` variable.

```
$) CURRENT_DATE="20140220"
$) date -d $CURRENT_DATE
Thu Feb 20 00:00:00 IST 2014
```

To store the date into a variable, try using

```
$) CURRENT_DATE_TMP=`date +%Y%m%d`
$) echo $CURRENT_DATE_TMP
20140704
```

**EDIT**

To print an existing date into a new format, use

```
$ CURRENT_DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
$ echo $CURRENT_DATE 
2014-07-04
$ date -d$CURRENT_DATE "+%Y%m%d"
20140704
```

Better still, wrap the `$CURRENT_DATE` variable within quotes, so that dates with spaces don't break anything.

```
$ CURRENT_DATE=`date`
$ echo $CURRENT_DATE 
Fri Jul 4 17:59:45 IST 2014
$ date -d"$CURRENT_DATE" "+%Y%m%d"
20140704
$ date -d$CURRENT_DATE "+%Y%m%d"
date: extra operand ‘4’
```

In your current example, you have a space after the `-d` flag, remove it.

Comment: current date is not today's date. It should be in the variable. Eg. CURRENT_DATE may have value 2014-03-10 in it.

Comment: i don't want to store current date in variable. I have date in format YYYY-MM-DD in variable CURRENT_DATE and I want to get the date in format YYYYMMDD in variable CURRENT_DATE_tmp.

Comment: and this should be in script.

Comment: It looks like `date -d "$CURRENT" "+%Y%m%d"` works in bash; that is, if there are no spaces in $CURRENT, then either eliminating the space _or_ putting $CURRENT in quotes will fix the problem. In any case, the answer (as edited) seems more than adequate to me.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah, Initially I thought the OP was trying to print date and had misread the flags, so I was thinking on those lines. It was when he clarified in the comments above that I realised what he was trying to do.

Comment: @user3153014 Were you able to solve this? Don't forget to accpet and upvote, if my answer helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the variable is unset or empty, and you did not quote the variable:

```
$ CURRENT_DATE=""
$ CURRENT_DATE_tmp=$(date -d $CURRENT_DATE +%Y%m%d)
date: invalid date ‘+%Y%m%d’
```

If you use quotes, no error:

```
$ CURRENT_DATE_tmp=$(date -d "$CURRENT_DATE" +%Y%m%d)
$ echo $CURRENT_DATE_tmp
20140704
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been mentioned in a comment, but you must make sure there is actually a value in the variable $CURRENT if you want to do what you are trying to do.
Try inserting these two lines in your script:

```
echo date is =$CURRENT=
date -d "$CURRENT" "+%Y%m%d"
```

If one of the lines of output appears like the one below, then you have neglected to set
`$CURRENT` to a non-empty string:

```
date is ==
```

Trying various variations of `date -d "$CURRENT" "+%Y%m%d"` (with or without quotes, with or without space after `-d`) when `$CURRENT` is an empty string, either I see the "invalid date" error or I get today's date.