# How do I get a date of yesterday in expect

Tags: linux, expect

I write a expect script 1.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set yest [exec `date -d "yesterday" '+%Y%m%d'`]
send_user $yest
exit 1
```

And run in linux ,use `expect -d ./1.sh`
But I get this error:

```
expect version 5.44.1.15
executing commands from command file ./1.sh
invalid command name "/bin/date"
    while executing
"date -d "yesterday" '+%Y%m%d'"
    invoked from within
"set yest [date -d "yesterday" '+%Y%m%d']"
```

So,how do I fix this.I googled somethings and have no idea.
I find `clock` to instead `date`:

```
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/clock.htm
```

And I get a way to run expect in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
expect <<!
## expect code ##
!
```

Finally use this way to get yesterday string in `expect script`:

```
set yest [clock scan "yesterday"]
set yest1 [clock format $yest -format {%Y%m%d}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid date error in the date command linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573904/invalid-date-error-in-the-date-command-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set yest [ exec /bin/date -d "yesterday" +%Y%m%d]
send_user $yest
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

**For yesterday :**

```
date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%d%m'
```

**For day before yesterday :**

```
date -d '-2 day' '+%Y%d%m'
```

Comment: But I think the point of this error is : `invalid command name "date"`, the commands `date -d "yesterday" '+%Y%m%d'` also worked fine in the linux

Comment: i m not clear with your question. If your code works fine then y are u getting error?